# Laravel: Errors/Messages not being fetched in view

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-5.1

I'm doing the following:

```
if(Request::get('file') == 'yes' && Request::file('file_name') == null){
                return Redirect::back()
                ->withInput()
                ->withErrors("You did not select file")
                ->with('message', 'There were validation errors.');
                return false;
            }
```

But it is not fetching back to view no matter what. I tried to use `errors` and `$message`. Nothing worked. Debugger shows that message are being stored in the session.

In view I did the following:

```
<div style="margin-top: 10%;" class="alert alert-danger">
            <? print_r($message); ?>
                show here
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are redirecting back, you have to access your variable with the [session()](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session#basic-usage) helper or the [Session::get()](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Session/Store.html#method_get) facade.

You should then do something like

`{{ session('message') }}`

In your case, `session('message')` is not an array so no need to use `print_r()`.